# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning only thrown in function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, warnings

I am using a Jupyter notebook (not sure if this is relevant) and I am having trouble understanding why Pandas is throwing the SettingWithCopyWarning but only under a certain condition.

Here is the first version of my code:

```
def read_in_yearly_data(file_name):
    print('\t%s' % file_name)

    df = pd.read_csv('../' + file_name + '.csv', header=None)

    # Drop the first 4 columns, and set names of the remaining 4 columns
    for i in range(4):
        del df[i]

    df.columns = ['Part_Name', 'Date', 'Description', 'Units']

    return df

yearly_data = []
for year in ['09', '10', '11']:
    yearly_data.append(read_in_yearly_data('20' + year + ' data'))

all_data = pd.concat(yearly_data, axis=0, join='outer')

parts_to_exclude = misc.PART_NAMES
all_data = all_data.query('Part not in @parts_to_exclude')

all_data['Units'] = all_data['Units'].apply(lambda x: hf.to_int(x))
```

And the second version (wraps the code in a function):

```
def read_in_yearly_data(file_name):
    print('\t%s' % file_name)

    df = pd.read_csv('../' + file_name + '.csv', header=None)

    # Drop the first 4 columns, and set names of the remaining 4 columns
    for i in range(4):
        del df[i]

    df.columns = ['Part_Name', 'Date', 'Description', 'Units']

    return df

def myfunc():
    yearly_data = []
    for year in ['09', '10', '11']:
        yearly_data.append(read_in_yearly_data('20' + year + ' data'))

    all_data = pd.concat(yearly_data, axis=0, join='outer')

    parts_to_exclude = misc.PART_NAMES
    all_data = all_data.query('Part not in @parts_to_exclude')

    all_data['Units'] = all_data['Units'].apply(lambda x: hf.to_int(x))

my_func()
```

The call `hf.to_int(x)` takes the 'Units' and converts it to an integer (some of the units are stored as strings and have commas, e.g., '2,000.0'.

The first version of the code DOES NOT produce the warning while the second version does.

Even changing the last line to

```
all_data.loc[:, 'Units'] = all_data['Units'].apply(lambda x: hf.to_int(x))
```

in the second version does not change anything, and I am struggling to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The error should go away if you change

```
all_data = all_data.query('Part not in @parts_to_exclude')
```

To:

```
all_data = all_data.query('Part not in @parts_to_exclude').copy()
```

I'm still not quite clear why it didn't give you an error when it's not in a function.